# Why djangoRest framework retrieveAPIView not able to filter with email?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use retrieveAPIView to look up details based on 'email'. But its throwing error:

```
Not Found: /apii/list/
[27/May/2021 19:53:28] "GET /apii/list/?email=%22xxx.zzz@gmail.com%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 2801
```

project level urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('apii/', include('AUTHENTICATION.urls')),
]
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', loginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^list/(?P<email>[\w\-]+)/$', IndividualUserDetails.as_view(), name='list'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
class IndividualUserDetails(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = NewEmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
```

The url I am entering in postman is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/apii/list/?email="xxx.zzz@gmail.com"`

I am assuming I am calling the url in a wrong way may be.

Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: Don't put those quotes `"` in the url, simply write `?email=xxx.zzz@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you, I tried, but not working

Comment: Your url pattern is `list/(?P<email>[\w\-]+)/`, why do you pass it as a querystring / GET parameter in that case? Try: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/apii/list/xxx.zzz@gmail.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url pattern is like so:

```
re_path(r'^list/(?P<email>[\w\-]+)/$', IndividualUserDetails.as_view(), name='list'),
```

Yet you try to pass the email as a GET parameter (`?email="xxx.zzz@gmail.com"`)and not as a part of the url itself. You need to pass the email as part of the url itself, hence your url should be like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/apii/list/xxx.zzz@gmail.com/
```

Furthermore your pattern will fail in matching your email as `[\w\-]+` will not match `.`, `@`, etc. Instead simply use `path` and the `str` url converter:

```
path(r'list/<str:email>/', IndividualUserDetails.as_view(), name='list'),
```

Comment: hit the bulls eye. Thank you